# Is there an upper limit for the length of row keys?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I want to know whether there's a maximum length for the row key values in Google's BigTable.

I'm aware the documentation recommends hashing as a potential solution to create keys of the same length, but in my scenario I can group related data better if I include a file path in my key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Cloud Bigtable:

The maximum length for row keys is 4KiB.

The maximum length for column qualifiers is 16 KiB.

This info is on the [quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/quotas#limits) page in the documentation.

Comment: I am an SRE at Google who works on Cloud Bigtable. Working on getting this answer into official documentation so I can cite it in my answer, should be there soon.

Comment: This is now officially documented.

Comment: This is a very old question, but I thought I might add: It seems that 4 KiB is NOT an actual hard limit, but a recommendation. I found this supposed google interview notes repository where it says that the hard limit for a row key is actually 64KB
https://github.com/jguamie/system-design/blob/master/notes/bigtable.md

Answer (score 3):

We recommend relatively short row keys, but a file path should be ok.  The one thing you'll want to make sure is that there is some uniqueness at the start of the key.

Ie. if you are adding something like:

```
/Users/lesv/Downloads/abc.java
/Users/lesv/Downloads/abc.res
/Users/lesv/Downloads/def.java
```

It might be better to invert the path like:

```
java.abc/Downloads/lesv/Users
res.abc/Downloads/lesv/Users
java.def/Downloads/lesv/Users
```

To get some uniqueness at the start of the path.

Comment: It's good to know a file path should be okay. The path will be the second half of the key, so it will avoid hotspotting. I've upvoted as this has solved my underlying question, but I'll leave it open as I'm still not sure _exactly_ how long a key can be in length. Thanks.

Comment: Great, thank you. I don't plan on using one anywhere close to that big. It's just nice to have some insurance by having an idea of the upper limit. I appreciate this probably feels like one of those "If you need to ask, you're probably doing something wrong" situations.